# how to use for loop to iterating url index to collect the data

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am a newbie in python. I want to write a for loop to iterate the index in order to pull the data.

Here is my code:

```
url90=[]
for i in range(-90,0):
 url90.append('http://staging.foglogic.com/api/v1/index.php/accounts/34/reports/bcjobs?cmd=json&datestr=today&**index=i**&filter={}&filterOverride=0&su=1')
```

I want index=i which from range(-90,0), however the python consider my i as  a string instead of a integer.

my result give me 90 identical url :

```
'http://staging.foglogic.com/api/v1/index.php/accounts/34/reports/bcjobs?cmd=json&datestr=today&index=i&filter={}&filterOverride=0&su=1'
```

Is there anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `'http://staging.foglogic.com/api/v1/index.php/accounts/34/reports/bcjobs?cmd=json&datestr=today&index={}&filter={}&filterOverride=0&su=1'.format(i, "{}")`

Comment: Did you think that `i` variable will be automatically replaced in the string? No, it does not work that way. Use `.format`. See http://ideone.com/0isAAv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that `i` variable will automatically be used in the string used to populate the list, you are wrong. It does not work that way. Use `.format`:

```
url90=[]
for i in range(-90,0):
    url90.append('http://staging.foglogic.com/api/v1/index.php/accounts/34/reports/bcjobs?cmd=json&datestr=today&index={0}&filter={{}}&filterOverride=0&su=1'.format(i))
print("\n".join(url90))
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/0isAAv)

Note that literal `{` and `}` in the format string must be doubled (see `index={0}`). The `{0}` is a placeholder for the `i` variable (see `filter={{}}`) that is the first and only argument to the method.